# Retrieving values from a hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashtable

Good Evening/Morning all,

Yesterday i recieved some help on how to loop through a table and assign its values to a hashtable which i now working correctly with the below code, there are a total of 10 questions that are returned from the below method

```
public Hashtable GetExamAnswers(int UserID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection Connection = new SQLAccess().CreateConnection();
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("GetAllExamAnswersForUser", Connection);
            Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            SqlDataReader da = Command.ExecuteReader();
            int i = 1;
            while (da.Read())
            {
                Details.Add("QuestionNumber" + i, da["UserAnswer"]);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            Connection.Close();
            da.Close();
            return Details;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem Updating the User`s Details");
            return Details;
        }
    }
```

When i hover over "Details" its laid out like this

```
Question1      4
Question2      5
Question3      Y
Question4      9
Question5      10
```

Etc all the way down to Question10

Im now trying to get the values out of the hashtable and assign the relevant value to the relevant textbox

heres my code after it has returned from the above method

```
ExamAnswers = obj_Methods.GetExamAnswers(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uid"]));
        if (ExamAnswers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry dict in ExamAnswers)
            {
              Q1Answer.Text = dict......;
              Q2Answer.Text = dict......;
              Q3Answer.Text = dict......;

            }
        }
```

ExamAnswers is a hashtable and holds the values that are returned, im trying to assign Q1answer.Text with Question1`s value thats in ExamAnswers but im struggling on how to achieve this, i tried to say

```
Q1Answer.Text = ExamAnswers.key["Question1"].value;
```

But with not avail, can someone help me with a solution.

Thank you

Comment: what does ExamAnswers.key["Question1"].value return

Comment: it doesnt allow me to use value at the end i get the following error 'object' doe not contain a definition for 'value'

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a situation in which you would use a `foreach` statement, since you know the keys ahead of time and they map to only one control. You would simply do the code you posted, where

```
Q1Answer.Text = ExamAnswers["Question1"].ToString();
```

Comment: Iv just tried the above but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Is `Q1Answer` and `ExamAnswers` both non null when you code is hit?

Answer (score 0):

Do it simplier:

```
        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
        hash.Add(1, "a");
        hash.Add(2, "b");

        string a = hash[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the key as `'QuestionNumber' + i` instead of `'Question' + i` in your first code snippet.  Make sure you're looking for the right key value.

Also you don't need to loop through the ExamAnswers:

```
ExamAnswers = obj_Methods.GetExamAnswers(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uid"]));

if (ExamAnswers.Count > 0)
{
      Q1Answer.Text = ExamAnswers["QuestionNumber1"].value;
      Q2Answer.Text = ExamAnswers["QuestionNumber2"].value;
      Q3Answer.Text = ExamAnswers["QuestionNumber3"].value;
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my stupid mistake! it not works with Q1Answer.Text = ExamAnswers["QuestionNumber1"].tostring();

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case you probably want to use an array to store your answers.  There is no benefit to using a hashtable in this example.